# Rasa Escaping in Windows - Error in Documentation

Tags: python, curl, cmd, anaconda, rasa-nlu

I'm doing the tutorial from official rasa page (http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html). Now i want to test my model. I have this command:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:5000/parse" -d "{/"q/":/"I am looking for Mexican food/"}" | python -m json.tool
```

The output from cmd is:
[image]

So there are those error Messages:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: am
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: looking
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: for
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Mexican
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 6
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The connection to the local server is valid, because on server side there is this error message:
[image]

"Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes". But the tutorial says, that I - as a Windows user - have to Escape the string. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think RASA docs have error. Try escaping with back slash \ instead of /

```
curl -X POST "localhost:5000/parse" -d "{\"q\":\"I am looking for Mexican food\"}" | python -m json.tool
```

or use ^ insted of / if \ does not work either.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this fast and right answer! \ instead of / is the right answer.